# PyQt4 Segmentation Fault when using .connect after compiling with Cython

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pyqt4, cython, cythonize

I have been developing a Qt GUI and thought to compile it with Cython as there are some OpenGL+Trimesh bits that would really benefit from Cython.

The project compiles, but seems to break the '.connect' functionality as it immediately segmentation faults when it tries to define it.

for example this line:

```
self.btn_geometry_autofit.clicked.connect(self.autofit)
```

will segmentation fault along with every other '.connect'.

I am compiling the project and calling it as a module in a separate script. When everything is Python it will work fine. The GUI pops up and everything loads. But after compilation the program will seg fault on the '.connect' as mentioned before.

Is this a known issue with Cython? Cython documentation says it works fine with PyQt so it seems strange that it is causing this seg fault.

Comment: I have occassionally seen issues with passing Cython functions to C/C++ code (including PyQt) in situations where Python functions work. If you use `*args` I've seen that produce a segfault. However, this looks more like a bug report than an question, so it's probably more useful to generate a minimal example and submit it to [the github page](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues)

Comment: You have not included versions for Python, Cython, OS, x86/x64, C/C++ compiler

Comment: Python 2.7, latest Cython, Linux or Ubuntu (whichever uses sudo apt), 64 bit, gcc compiler (unsure of version but unlikely to be ancient)

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know why the error appeared, but one can avoid it by changing initial click event to `QObject.connect(self.btn_geometry_autofit, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.autofit)`.
It worked for me.